# Toolbar button not showing

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I am trying to create a push segue between two view controllers using a button in the bottom toolbar. I am trying to do it in interface builder and when I build the app to the simulator, the button doesn't show up. Am I doing this wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it, I completely removed the viewcontroller and readded it and it started to work. /shrug